# Can i configure the tcp SYN retransmission interval?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, android

As far as I know SYN retransmissions: with rounding they occur 1, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, and then 64 seconds apart.
I want to do this on different interval time.
what is the name of this parameter?

can I control on it in android and windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows**:

You can only control the first retransmission with **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\ID**.  After this, the retransmitted SYN packets are dynamically controlled (Source: [KB 170359](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170359))

**Edit**:

Per discussion in the comments, it appears that the KB article I referenced is flawed for Windows 7; it seems that changing SYN retransmission parameters is not supported.

Comment: is there any name for this parameter ? only for syn retransmission? is it the RTO?

Comment: It is called `TCPInitialRtt`, used for the first SYN retransmission.  RTO is controlled indirectly with `TcpMaxDataRetransmissions`, but that isn't a timeout per-se... it's the number of attempts before Windows aborts the connection

Comment: I dont see this key. do i need to add it? dosnt it part of the TCP RFC? do you know how to do it in android? or a good search key words for this. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: I haven't found android information, you might try [so] for that question.  Add this to Win7 Enterprise if it isn't there.

Comment: added, disable and enable the adapter and restart the computer, dosnt take affect. any idea? thank you!!!!

Comment: Have you rebooted yet?

Comment: sure. in additional in this url  - http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc739819%28v=ws.10%29 its in second so also tried this :(

Comment: seems that not rellevant for windows7 - http://emeowctrl.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/200/

Comment: well, it's certainly possible, but it means the MSDN KB article is flawed