# Delay TCP SYN retransmission on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp

Our application connects to a device on a radio network. The network has to wake up the device before it can communicate which takes about 3 seconds. In this 3 seconds our CentOS (Linux 3.10.0-957.62.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) machines sends 2 retransmissions of the TCP SYN packet. The retransmission cause problems on the radio network so I'd like to wait with retransmissions for at least 3 seconds.

Lowering `tcp_syn_retries` doesn't really change the first retries and gives unwanted behavior when configured below 4 (which is also [not advised](http://willbryant.net/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout)). It just reduces retries but still follows the same pattern of retries (just less of them).

Setting `tcp_frto` to `1` and `setting tcp_low_latency` to `1` did not have the desired effect.

A similar question for Windows is posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/412266/can-i-configure-the-tcp-syn-retransmission-interval)

How do I change the TCP SYN retransmission schema on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

The tcp retransmission of the syn is related with the receive timeout (`rto`) value (see the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L3008)). By default it equals 1 second (defined [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L384) and [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/include/net/tcp.h#L136); min = 0.2 sec, max = 120 sec).

You can change the rto value for specified route with `ip` util.

```
ip route replace 0/0 via <wifi-gw> dev <wifi-iface> rto_min 5s
```

But the application itself can change the rto value with the setsockopt call.

Comment: I added the route with `rto_min` set to 5s but didn't see any change, still retransmissions after 1 and 3 seconds for the SYN packets. In the source I see in `tcp_connect_init` this: `inet_csk(sk)->icsk_rto = TCP_TIMEOUT_INIT;` and `TCP_TIMEOUT_INIT` is hardcoded. Does this mean I can't change this? Does rto_min only influence retransmissions after successful connection?